# JS, prototype: Having a constructor, how can I get an instance?

Tags: javascript, constructor

A model in my code receives a constructor at some point:

```
this.defaultView = WJCard;
```

WJCard is a simple prototype:

```
function WJCard() {...}
```

At some point, the model needs to create a WJCard instance based on the this.defaultView property.
I thought the following would help, but I'm wrong:

```
WJModel.prototype.render = function(classname) {

if (classname) {
    this.view = this.defaultView.call(); // Returns null :(
    // ...
}

    /. ...
```

}

I've tried a bit of everything with no success. Can anybody help me?

---

Corrected code thanks to answer...

```
WJModel.prototype.render = function(classname) {

if (classname) {
    this.view = new classname(); // works fine this way!
    // ...
}

    /. ...
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `new` as usual:

```
this.view = new this.defaultView();
```

Comment: Hey yes indeed... Now it seems obvious ;-) Updated the post with the corrected code. Thanks man.